# How to route specific port traffic on one domain to multiple Azure App Services?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway, azure-traffic-manager, azure-load-balancer

How would one route a domain's port traffic to multiple AppServices (not VMs):

```
https://www.example.com:80 (Website) --> AppService A
https://www.example.com:2000 (WebService) --> AppService B or AppService A/Slot 1
https://www.example.com:3000 (WebService) --> AppService C or AppService A/Slot 2
```

Would this be best accomplished with an Application Gateway? Can it be done with a Load Balancer or Traffic Manager? Can it be routed to Deployment Slots?

Comment: Traffic Manager definitely not. It operates at DNS level so has no concept of ports.

Comment: Thx @juunas . I'm thinking that because all three apps need to operate behind the same domain, separate app services won't work with a load balancer because I don't think two app services can have the same custom domain. Now, if the domain and SSL are on the App Gtwy, then the app svcs could keep their azure domains. To use a load balancer (to save $), we'd probably have to use one app svc with virtual directories?

Comment: Yeah you probably won't be able to add the domain to multiple app services.. Virtual directories could be a relatively cheap way yes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @juunas comment, the traffic manager works at the DNS level, it does not work on routing application based on the port for HTTP/HTTPS traffic.

For routing multiple app services based on each port, you could consider [Azure application gateway with path-based routing riles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-url-route-portal) and [Azure front door](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-overview#url-based-routing). However, that deployment will be complex and it will be very expensive.

Moreover, it does not allow to add the same domain for multiple different public services. So you can add the domain to one app service then use virtual directories. It is a relatively cheap way. Refer to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/0cbdbd8e-2112-4c7b-8871-7a907bf1de37/how-can-i-create-a-virtual-directory-with-azure-app-service?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) to create a virtual directory.

Comment: We were able to achieve this with the Application Gateway. We did not find Front Door to be necessary as we do not offer a global service.